# How to added specific Android code to Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have an application which runs correctly without any issue $ I added Java code to it to use a method channel and the problem is that the application isn't able to run sound microphone camera and did not show me any authorization to accept using camera or sound $.

The code which I added from Android works correctly and show me exactly what I want.

```
package com.example.akk;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

//import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final  String CHANNEL="samples.flutter.dev/battery";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
        new  MethodChannel(getFlutterView(),CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall,MethodChannel.Result result ){
             if(methodCall.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")){
                 int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

                 if (batteryLevel != -1) {
                     result.success(batteryLevel);
                 } else {
                     result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
                 }
             } else {
                 result.notImplemented();
             }

             }

        });


    }
    private int getBatteryLevel() {
        // int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);


        int deviceHealth;
        int x=10;

        Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).
                registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        deviceHealth = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0));




        if(deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD){

            x=0;        }

        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD){

            x=1;        }

        if(deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT){

            x=2;        }

        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE){

            x=3;        }

        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN){

            x=4;        }
        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE){

            x=5;        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

i need some helps and thank you

Comment: Please show your code to use the camera or mic... you need to explicitly check if you have permission if you don't, asking for it.

Comment: i have permission from the android manifesste.xml